# Where are my installed apps? (Ubuntu 9.10)

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10

I'm in the process of moving from XP to Linux. (I'm new to Linux)

I have succesfully installed Apache, MySQL and PHP on my desktop, using the SPM. Apache seems to have been succesfully installed (I can access http://localhost on my machine) - however, there are a few "problems":

## Apache

i). I cannot locate the Apache access log or error log files
ii). I cannot start/stop the service - how may I do this?
iii). Cannot locate httpd.conf

## PHP

I accidentally installed XCache and APC (caused a SEG-V). I uninstalled XCache, but it seems I need to edit the php.ini file as well, since PHP warns that it cannot find the XCache module - probelm is I cannot php.ini on my machine

## MySQL

Again, no interface provided to start/stop the daemon/service - so I cant start mySQL

## PhpMyadmin

I dont know where this is installed and so I cant navigate to it in my browser (even if I knew where it was installed, I cant find httpd.conf on my machine

Comment: Apache should be somewhere under /etc, you can start stop by running "apacectl start" or "apachectl stop"

Answer (score 3):

### Apache

Log:   /var/log/apache2

Conf:  /etc/apache2

Start: sudo service apache2 start

Stop: sudo service apache2 stop

---

### PHP

php.ini:  /etc/php5/apache2/php.ini

---

### MySQL

Start:   sudo service mysqld start

Stop:   sudo service mysqld stop

---

### PHPMyAdmin

Browse to:   http://127.0.0.1/phpmyadmin

See /etc/apache2/available-sites to find files

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you !!! (this is why I *LOVE* this website)

Comment: I forgot to ask this earlier (probably an obvious one - since I havent tried yet), but here goes:  how may I access the mySQL CLI (ommand line interface) on the Ubuntu box?  (it will help if I know where the executable was installed)

Comment: You should be able to run it my typing *mysql* at the command line, meaning it should be in your path. Not at my Ubuntu box right now to verify location. But you can use the *locate* command.

Answer (score 0):

Look in /etc/init.d for your startup/shutdown scripts. Ubuntu does not provide a "service" or "chkconfig" frontend.

Use the command "locate" to find particular files.

Comment: Ubuntu does provide "service"

Comment: My 8.04 installs do not provide the command: service. Perhaps this has been added since that release, or is an optional package install.

Comment: Added after I think. 9.04 and 9.10 both have for sure.

Answer (score 0):

There are a ton of tutorials out there on how to set up a LAMP (Linux, Apache, MySql, PHP) server on Ubuntu. If I were you, I'd just follow the steps in one of those tutorials.

This one is nice, because it also shows how to test all the installed services:
[LAMP How-To Ubuntu 9.10](http://tuxtweaks.com/2009/10/install-lamp-on-ubuntu-9-10-karmic-koala/).

Answer (score 0):

Ubuntu, like most modern Unix variants, uses a "package" system to keep track of where your installed applications are.  In reality, they are installed *all over* your file system, heavily intermingled - the package system keeps track of them all and makes sure there are no conflicts.  There is no single place where, like there was in DOS and Windows, where the program "was", where it "lived", so to speak - in Unix, an application puts its files all over the file system according to category, like configuration files go inside `/etc`, log files go in `/var/log`, etc.  The [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/) specifies a common organizational scheme that most Linux distributions follow.

Also Ubuntu, like Debian, has a common place for documentation for a package, so if you ever install a package and wonder "Now what?", you should look in the directory `/usr/share/doc/`*`packagename`* for a file called `README.Debian.gz` - it'll most often tell you what you should do next.